# Check and fetch the exact match in lucene.net

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

I tried with PhraseQuery and MultiPhraseQuery to find the exact line match. It is pulling records similar to wildcard search. Tried with Index.Not_Analysed too but no luck.

The data looks like below:

```
<Records>
<Record>
<Ingridents>Organic Sauce</Ingridents>
</Record>
<Record>
<Ingridents>Pure Organic Sauce</Ingridents>
</Record>
</Records>
```

When I search with "Organic Sauce" it should fetch record1 but it is fetching two records because of matching. But I'm expecting to fetch the entire sentence match then only it should fetch. Guide me if anyone faced this issue.

My Custom Analyser:

```
public class HybridSearchAnalyzer : Analyzer
    {
        protected override TokenStreamComponents CreateComponents(string fieldName, TextReader reader)
        {
            Tokenizer tokenizer = new StandardTokenizer(LuceneVersion.LUCENE_48, reader);
            TokenStream result = new StopFilter(LuceneVersion.LUCENE_48, tokenizer, StopAnalyzer.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS_SET);
            result = new LowerCaseFilter(LuceneVersion.LUCENE_48, result);
            return new TokenStreamComponents(tokenizer, result);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the index to be based on the whole field rather then the individual words then you need to make sure the field (ingredients in this case) is a `StringField` rather then a `TextField` when you add it to the document.

String fields are not tokenized.