# Lucene search to match exact element in Umbraco array

Tags: umbraco, lucene.net

I'm trying to search Umbraco (v10) tags, which are stored as an array.  Regardless of whether they are stored in CSV or JSON, I can't force an exact match.

For example, one article has tags containing `"foo bar"`, while a second article has tags containing `"foo"`.

If I use Lucene to search for `foo`, I get both articles returned.  I do not want to match `"foo bar"`.

This is my code:

```cs
IBooleanOperation query = _externalIndex.Searcher
    .CreateQuery("content", BooleanOperation.And)
    .NodeTypeAlias(modelTypeAlias)
    .And()
    //.Field("tags", tag);
    .NativeQuery($"tags:\"{tag}\"");
```

I have tried using `NativeQuery`, wrapping my tag in quotes, using regex to match start/end of the string, using parenthesis to indicate a set of matches.
I cannot identify a way to isolate an exact match.

Answer (score 1):

While your question is slightly different the [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75206364/check-and-fetch-the-exact-match-in-lucene-net), the answer is basically the same.

If you want the index to be based on the whole field rather then the individual words then you need to make sure the field is indexed as a `StringField` rather then a `TextField`.

String fields are not tokenized.

Answer (score 1):

RonC's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75311732/5329728) pointed me in the right direction, but it was more complicated than that.

I needed to split the JSON array of tags into individual elements, using the `TransformingIndexValues` event handler, and store them in a new field `tagsSplit`:

```cs
private void TransformTagsValues(object? sender, IndexingItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ValueSet.Category != "content")
    {
        return;
    }

    Dictionary<string, List<object>> updatedValues = e.ValueSet.Values.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value.ToList());
    if (!updatedValues.ContainsKey("tags"))
    {
        return;
    }

    JArray tagsArray = JArray.Parse(updatedValues["tags"].Single().ToString()!);
    updatedValues["tagsSplit"] = tagsArray.Select(token => (object)token.Value<string>()!).ToList();
    e.SetValues(updatedValues.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => (IEnumerable<object>)x.Value));
}
```

Then I needed to configure the indexer to treat the field values as `Raw` (which internally uses `StringField`):

```cs
public void Configure(string name, LuceneDirectoryIndexOptions options)
{
    if (name.Equals(UmbracoIndexes.ExternalIndexName))
    {
        options.FieldDefinitions.AddOrUpdate(new FieldDefinition("tagsSplit", FieldDefinitionTypes.Raw));
    }
}
```

Now finally if I query using field:

```cs
IBooleanOperation query = _externalIndex.Searcher
    .CreateQuery("content", BooleanOperation.And)
    .NodeTypeAlias(modelTypeAlias)
    .And()
    .Field("tagsSplit", tag);
```

It gives me an exact match.
It is also case-sensitive, but since I'm searching by existing tags and not free-text, that is fine for my use-case.